# Check a javascript variable matches a substring using regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript variable that contains string value. I want to check whether the string contains `UID_PK` in it. How can I match this string to match the substring "`UID_PK`" using regex expression?

For example `var id="UID_PK:1234"`

Comment: This does not need Regex to be solved, normal string manipulation can do it.

Answer (score 2):

No regular expressions needed, you can use [`indexOf` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if(id.indexOf("UID_PK") > -1) {
    // id contains "UID_PK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var id="UID_PK:1234"
if( id.match( /UID_PK/ )) alert( 'match' );
```

next time try to read dome documentation on regex in javascript , this is the most simple example